# Updating collection with condition on nested documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

Not able to update Mongo collection using Mongoose (in NestJS) with matching conditions on nested documents

Here is the code

Interfaces

```
    export interface ISubscription {
      name: string;
      category: string;
      ....
    }
    export interface IPlan {
      name: string;
      status: string;
      charges?: [ICharge];
    }
    export interface IEvent {
      subscription: ISubscription;
      plan: IPlan;
      date: Date;
      type: string;
      amount: number;
      data: any;
      billed: boolean;
    }
```

Subscription Schema

```
    interface SubscriptionDocument extends ISubscription, Document {}
    
    const SubscriptionSchemaFields: Record<keyof ISubscription, any> = {
      name: String,
      category: String,
    ........
    
    };
    const SubscriptionSchema = new Schema(SubscriptionSchemaFields);
    
    const Subscription = model<SubscriptionDocument>(
      'Subscription',
      SubscriptionSchema,
    );
    
    export { SubscriptionDocument, SubscriptionSchema, Subscription };
```

Event Schema Definition

```
    interface EventDocument extends IEvent, Document {}
    
    const EventSchemaFields: Record<keyof IEvent, any> = {
      subscription: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Subscription',
      },
      plan: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Plan',
      },
      date: Date,
      type: String,
      amount: Number,
      data: Object,
      billed: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
      },
    };
    const EventSchema = new Schema(EventSchemaFields);
    
    const Event = model<EventDocument>('Event', EventSchema);
    
    export { EventDocument, EventSchema, Event };
```

I am calculating the bill amount as

```
    const balanceCalc = await this.eventModel.aggregate([
      {
        $match: {
          subscription: { $eq: Types.ObjectId(instantBill.subscription) },
          plan: { $eq: Types.ObjectId(instantBill.plan) },
          billed: { $eq: false },
        },
      },
      {
        $group: {
          _id: null,
          sumamount: { $sum: '$amount' },
        },
      },
    ]);
```

I need to update the event billed property to true after calculating and generating the bill.
The issue is not able to update the billed property with subscription and plan ID

```
const eventupdate = await this.eventModel.updateMany(
      {
        'subscription._id': subscriptionId,
        'plan._id': planId,
        billed: false,
      },
      { $set: { billed: true } },
    );
```

What I'm doing here is updating the billed property by matching all the events with subscription and plan ID. both subscriptionId and planId are strings.

But no errors and no updating of the events. Tried different ways but got errors at condition. Can someone please help resolve this issue? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Checked the value of `eventupdate`. You should able to know whether is your filter condition match any document with `matchedCount`. *both subscriptionId and planId are strings*, have  you tried to convert these values to `ObjectId` and pass it within the filter criteria. Unmatched value type against the document schema could also be a potential root cause that you unable to query any document.

Comment: @YongShun thank you for your response. Tried with Object id and also by adding to array and matching with $in. All are giving nModified=0 ie., no match